# seaborn's lmplot: KeyError [ ...] not in index; excel and csv import

Tags: python, excel, csv, seaborn

I'm very new to python, so please bear with me. I'm having trouble to visualize an excel/csv file with seaborn's lmplot. This code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/me/Documents/Jupyter Notebooks/Seaborn/Test.csv")
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
sns.lmplot(x=df["TestX"],y=df["TestY"], data=df)
```

gives me this error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-00ad8b882663> in <module>()
----> 1 sns.lmplot(x=df["TestX"],y=df["TestY"], data=df)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\regression.py in lmplot(x, y, data, hue, col, row, palette, col_wrap, size, aspect, markers, sharex, sharey, hue_order, col_order, row_order, legend, legend_out, x_estimator, x_bins, x_ci, scatter, fit_reg, ci, n_boot, units, order, logistic, lowess, robust, logx, x_partial, y_partial, truncate, x_jitter, y_jitter, scatter_kws, line_kws)
    550     need_cols = [x, y, hue, col, row, units, x_partial, y_partial]
    551     cols = np.unique([a for a in need_cols if a is not None]).tolist()
--> 552     data = data[cols]
    553 
    554     # Initialize the grid

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2131         if isinstance(key, (Series, np.ndarray, Index, list)):
   2132             # either boolean or fancy integer index
-> 2133             return self._getitem_array(key)
   2134         elif isinstance(key, DataFrame):
   2135             return self._getitem_frame(key)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _getitem_array(self, key)
   2175             return self._take(indexer, axis=0, convert=False)
   2176         else:
-> 2177             indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
   2178             return self._take(indexer, axis=1, convert=True)
   2179 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _convert_to_indexer(self, obj, axis, is_setter)
   1267                 if mask.any():
   1268                     raise KeyError('{mask} not in index'
-> 1269                                    .format(mask=objarr[mask]))
   1270 
   1271                 return _values_from_object(indexer)

KeyError: '[  2  23 231 234 242 321] not in index'
```

I figured there is something wrong with the index, but to me (as I said, I'm new to this) the index seems to be set right:

```
df.head()

    Asset   Paid    Organic
0   A   23  2
1   B   231     234
2   C   321     242
```

And when I use import Datasets, lmplot is working just fine:

```
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(color_codes=True)
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.lmplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips, hue="smoker")
```

What am I doing wrong? sns.regplot didn't give me that error, but I wanted to use hue, to make a much bigger dataset easier to understand. I tried many things to fix this and couldn't find any solution. xlxs and csv-files both give me this error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do **NOT** use

```
sns.lmplot(x=df["TestX"],y=df["TestY"], data=df)
```

From [the documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html) :

> **x, y :** *strings, optional*
>
> Input variables, these should be column names in data.

You can try again with:

```
sns.lmplot(x="TestX",y="TestY", data=df)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! This solved my problem.
PS: I hate myself now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set_theme(style="darkgrid")
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

sns.lmplot(x="Duration", y="Maxpulse", data=df)
plt.show()

plt.savefig(sys.stdout.buffer)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

"Duration" and "Maxpluse" are column names.

Here is the output of my code:

[image: Output]